# Set file description using lightning:fileUpload

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am using the [lightning:fileUpload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/example) function on my Lightning component. While working as described on the demo page, it does not show any way to set a File Description. Is this available as one of attributes for lightning:fileUpload element?

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="accept" type="List" default="['.jpg', '.jpeg']"/>
    <aura:attribute name="multiple" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <lightning:fileUpload  name="fileUploader"
                           label= "Demo Upload"
                           multiple="{!v.multiple}"
                           accept="{!v.accept}"
                           disabled="{!v.disabled}"
                           recordId="abcd"
                           onuploadfinished="{! c.handleUploadFinished }"/>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: The description you can set inside `handleUploadFinished` by doing server call as of now there is no other option, so in the `handleUploadFinished` event you will get `documentId` use this to attach the description with the file.

Comment: You you implying I'll have to update it after its been uploaded using DML?

Comment: Yes, you have to perform DML to update the document in `onuploadfinished` event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no out of the box feature to allow adding descriptions to files. But this can be achieved by first uploading the file as mentioned in the example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:fileUpload/documentation).

You can create a new attribute on your component to hold the description and set the value on the "onuploadfinished" callback where you can use the "documentId" to associate the file.

The psuedo code will look something like this -

**Component**

```
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="myRecordId" type="String" description="Record to which the files should be attached" />
    <aura:attribute name="fileDescription" type="String" description="..." />

    <lightning:fileUpload label="Attach receipt"
        name="fileUploader"
        multiple="true"
        accept=".pdf, .png"
        recordId="{!v.myRecordId}"
        onuploadfinished="{!c.handleUploadFinished}" />
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    handleUploadFinished: function (cmp, event) {
        // Get the uploaded file
        var uploadedFile = event.getParam("files")[0];
        var documentId = uploadedFile.documentId;

        var description = component.get("v.description");

        // Now perform a DML operation to save the description along with the document. Method will be something like this -
        saveDescription(documentId, description); // Use aura actions to call this method. This prototype is supposed to be implemented on the apex controller.
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this example. Helpful, though I hate this is the only way Salesforce lets you do it...